# I need a very fast help on a query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
airport_id "Airport id",
crew_type "Crew type",       
min(crew_age) "Minimum age",
Round(avg(crew_age),0) "Average age",
max(crew_age) "Maximum age"

FROM crew
GROUP by crew_type
```

Problem is on the second part. Second part is i need to get the airport name according to airport_id field. I do this:

```
SELECT 
crew.airport_id,
crew_type "Crew type",       
min(crew_age) "Minimum age",
Round(avg(crew_age),0) "Average age",
max(crew_age) "Maximum age",


airport.airport_name

FROM crew, airport
WHERE
crew.airport_id = airport.airport_id
GROUP by crew.crew_type
```

It works but airport_id  does not match with airport_name. Airport_id and airport_name  fields are all same.

Comment: Certification crowd sourced by Stackoverflow. You're joking right?

Comment: Surely the SQL engine in front of you is giving you a _very insightful error message_ right now.

Comment: Stupid me. OK. sorted. This was the only question i could not do.

Comment: `SELECT 'I could not solve the question. Sorry.';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you group all fields must be part of the group by or they must be used with an aggregate function like max, avg.

SELECT 
crew.airport_id,
crew_type "Crew type",
min(crew_age) "Minimum age",
Round(avg(crew_age),0) "Average age",
max(crew_age) "Maximum age",

airport.airport_name

FROM crew, airport
WHERE
crew.airport_id = airport.airport_id
GROUP by crew.airport_id, crew.crew_type, airport.airport_name